# Port game to android wear from Unity 5.4.4

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, wear-os

Hi I have a game that I have created on Unity 5. I want to port that game to Android Wear.

I have Moto 360
I saw few links but I had no success.

http://aa-games.blogspot.in/2015/05/unity3d-to-android-wear.html

Is there anyone who had sucess in this ... ?

Comment: Are you having any problem with your game on the watch? You have the physical device with you so why not try it?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1164046/how-to-port-game-on-android-wear.html

Comment: Yes I have Physical device with me..The error in above link are coming in emulator

Comment: When you get error like that, first you do is to create an empty project with just a simple unity hello world `Text`. No plugins no scripts. New Project with a Text. That way you'll know that the problem is not from your game.

Comment: Lol..That what I did. The above error is coming in empty project which is working perfectly on android Phone Did you saw the link - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1164046/how-to-port-game-on-android-wear.html ?

Comment: Ok. You are on the right track. Does that error show during compile or runtime?

Comment: runtime ... (feeling excited :P)

Comment: lol don't get your hopes up. Assuming I have the watch, It would have been easy to figure out what the problem is. Here, try UNITY 5.4.0B15 http://unity3d.com/unity/beta while downloading it, what version of Android is the watch running?

Comment: OS I have to check my battery just drained completely....but what abt this new unity 5.4.0B15 ? Do you meant that if I build in this Unity ver no error will come ?

Comment: **Do you meant that if I build in this Unity ver no error will come ?** I don't know. You are trying it to see if any bug fixes from 5.4.0B4 to 5.4.0B15 apply to your device. There are lots of Android crash fixes and the only way to know is if you try it.

Comment: But why did you suggested this particular verison on Unity. And have you ever tried building for android wear from Unity 5 ?

Comment: I was going to give up but I will give you another chance. Download 5.4.0B15 because it is the latest version with many bug fixes. Something I've said over and over again. **And have you ever tried building for android wear from Unity 5 ?** Yes with Google Glass.

Comment: Sorry my bad but the result is coming from Unity 5.3.5 only I am using latest unity version

Comment: Are you running this on the physical device or emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 tutorials out there that show you how to import Unity to Android Wear through Android Studio but they are mostly vague.

Basically, since Android Wear runs the same SDK as regular Android phones, you need to export a gradle build. Open a new project in Android Studio with a phone and wear module. Import your Unity Build, then copy paste all of the Unity values over to the wear module. This includes (Unity-classes.jar, JniLibs and assets) Then tweak a couple lines in the manifest and gradle. Add a way to detect screen shape and your good to go.

I went ahead and wrote up a how to step by step if you wan't to check it out. A big thank you to Pastille for helping me in the first place.

https://www.stonegolemstudio.com/post/unity3d-to-wear-os-tutorial

Comment: A link-only answer is discouraged. Please elaborate your answer and back it up with some links.

Comment: I asked this questioned about a year ago. Answer could be helpful for the devs who are still stuck. My project was shipped long time ago... :)